# Reading values from offline registry file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to read an **offline** registry file:

```
$product_name = Get-ItemProperty -Path "C:\temp\RegistryHives\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -name ProductName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProductName
```

Getting the below error. What would be the right way to access the offline registry file keys and values?

```
Get-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'C:\temp\RegistryHives\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' because it
does not exist.
At line:1 char:17
+ ... duct_name = Get-ItemProperty -Path "C:\temp\RegistryHives\SOFTWARE\Mi ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\temp\Registr...\CurrentVersion:String) [Get-ItemProperty], ItemNotFo
   undException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemPropertyCommand
```

Comment: `C:\temp\...` would be a path to a file, but you mention registry hive. I think you need to mount the Reg Hive then look at where you mounted it with `Get-ItemProperty`

Comment: the file in this case would be "Software". Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5):

You need to load the reg hive before accessing it. `reg.exe` can load hives with the `load` command`

```
Reg.exe load 'HKLM\TempHive' C:\temp\RegistryHives\SOFTWARE
$product_name = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\TempHive\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -name ProductName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProductName
Reg.exe unload 'HKLM\TempHive'
```

Comment: Won't using the HKLM hive require elevated permissions?  Is HKCU a better use-case here?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 The specifics of what they are trying to accomplish aren't listed, so I wouldn't know what the best use case is. HLKM is the example hive loaded in [Microsoft's documentation of reg.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-load) which was why I used it.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley `reg load` requires either `HKLM` or `HKU` as root key. You need elevated permissions for both.